# Erlang Cowboy Constraints Coding

Tags: erlang, constraints, handler, cowboy

```
{"/:myobj/get:id",Constraints, constraints_handler, [list]},
{"/:myobj/list",Constraints, constraints_handler, [list]},
{"/:myobj/save",Constraints, constraints_handler, [save]},
{"/:myobj/update",Constraints, constraints_handler, [update]},
{"/:myobj/delete",Constraints, constraints_handler, [delete]}
```

Please help me  code the Constraints where :myobj will be a string value without space and special chars. and :id will be int.

Comment: 1) What do you consider "special characters"?  2) Does "without" mean "removed" or "converted"? 3) Is the route you are interested in even correct?  Shouldn't the route be: `"/:myobj/get/:id"`

Answer (score 0):

**hello_erlang_app.erl**:

```
-module(hello_erlang_app).
-behaviour(application).

-export([start/2]).
-export([stop/1]).
-export([positive_fun/2]).

positive_fun(forward, Value) when Value > 0 -> 
    {ok, Value};
positive_fun(forward, _) ->
    {error, not_positive}.
%Not for route constraints:
%positive_fun(format_error, {not_positive, Value}) ->
%    io_lib:format("The value ~p is not an integer.", [Value]).

convert(forward, Value) ->
    DecodedValue = cow_qs:urldecode(Value),
    NoSpaces = re:replace(DecodedValue, " ", "", [global, {return, list}]),
    {ok, NoSpaces}. 

start(_Type, _Args) ->
    MyObjConstraints = { myobj, [fun convert/2] },
    IdConstraints = { id, [int, fun positive_fun/2] },

    IdRoute = { "/:myobj/get/:id", 
                 [MyObjConstraints, IdConstraints],  
                 id_handler, 
                 []
              }, %The last arg becomes the State 
                 %arg in the id_handler's init() method.

    CatchallRoute = {"/[...]", no_matching_route_handler, []},

    Dispatch = cowboy_router:compile([
        {'_', [IdRoute, CatchallRoute]}
    ]), 

    {ok, _} = cowboy:start_clear(my_http_listener,
        [{port, 8080}],
        #{env => #{dispatch => Dispatch} }
    ),

    hello_erlang_sup:start_link().


stop(_State) ->
    ok.
```

**id_handler.erl**:

```
-module(id_handler).
-behavior(cowboy_handler).

-export([init/2]).

init(Req0, State) -> %State comes from last argument of the route
    MyObj = cowboy_req:binding(myobj, Req0),
    Id = cowboy_req:binding(id, Req0),
    Reply = io_lib:format("Hello Erlang~nMyObj=~p~nId=~w~n", [MyObj, Id]),

    Req = cowboy_req:reply(200,
        #{<<"content-type">> => <<"text/plain">>},
        Reply,
        Req0),
    {ok, Req, State}.
```

**no_matching_route_handler.erl**:

```
-module(no_matching_route_handler).
-behavior(cowboy_handler).

-export([init/2]).

init(Req0, State) -> %State comes from last argument of the route
    Req = cowboy_req:reply(404,
        #{<<"content-type">> => <<"text/plain">>},
        <<"[ME] 404. Whoops! (No matching route!)">>,
        Req0),
    {ok, Req, State}.
```

**Makefile**:

```
PROJECT = hello_erlang
PROJECT_DESCRIPTION = New project
PROJECT_VERSION = 0.1.0

DEPS = cowboy
#dep_cowboy_commit = master
dep_cowboy_commit = 2.6.1


DEP_PLUGINS = cowboy

include erlang.mk
```

Some examples:

```
url in browser: http://localhost:8080/dog/get/1

response:

    Hello Erlang
    MyObj="dog"
    Id=1
```

---

```
url in browser: http://localhost:8080/dog/get/-4

response:

    [ME] 404. Whoops! (No matching route!)
```

---

```
url in browser: http://localhost:8080/h%20e%20l%20l%20o/get/1

response:

    Hello Erlang
    MyObj="hello"
    Id=1
```

---

```
url in browser: http://localhost:8080/hello%28%27arg%27%29/get/1

response:

    Hello Erlang
    MyObj="hello('arg')"
    Id=1
```

---

```
url in browser: http://localhost:8080/h%20e%20l%20l%20o%28%27arg%27%29/get/1

response:

    Hello Erlang
    MyObj="hello('arg')"
    Id=1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was really very helpful.